# thread Timer .cancel on program close

Tags: python, multithreading, wxpython

I have a threading Timer that runs a function every 60 seconds and prints a string to a textbox

```
def devPresent(self):
    stdout = self.deviceExists()
    exists = self.exactMatch(stdout, "device")
    if "device" in str(exists):
        self.progressBox.AppendText('TEST STILL HERE\n')
    else: 
        self.progressBox.AppendText('Device connection lost\n')
        self.rstBtn()
    t = threading.Timer(60, self.devPresent)
    t.start()
```

So this works  and TEST STILL HERE is printed to the progressBox, however when I close the window with the following def, it closes the main window but another one pops up and freezes.

```
 def closeWindow(self,e):
    t = self.devPresent
    t.cancel()
    time.sleep(3)
    self.Destroy()
```

Am I incorrectly closing the thread?

Comment: Strange, I'd expect this to give a `NameError` because `t` shouldn't be visible anywhere outside of `devPresent`.

Comment: yeah, I understand that, but didn't know how to correctly call it, I tried a few things but got errors each time. This is the furthest it gets with t.cancel()

Answer (score 0):

`t` won't be visible between class methods unless you make it an attribute of `self`. Try:

```
def devPresent(self):
    stdout = self.deviceExists()
    exists = self.exactMatch(stdout, "device")
    if "device" in str(exists):
        self.progressBox.AppendText('TEST STILL HERE\n')
    else: 
        self.progressBox.AppendText('Device connection lost\n')
        self.rstBtn()
    self.t = threading.Timer(60, self.devPresent)
    self.t.start()


 def closeWindow(self,e):
    self.t.cancel()
    time.sleep(3)
    self.Destroy()
```

Comment: thanks, this does work, but the program still freezes when closeWindow is called, if I completely remove all the threading stuff it goes back to working fine.